# Не отображаются данные в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, cursoradaper

По уроку https://skillberg.com/courses/android/lessons/loaders-cursorloader-rabotaem-s-contentprovider-ispolzuya-zagruzchiki/ пыталась реализовать вывод данных из БД в RecyclerView через Cursor, но почему-то данные не отображаются. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем причина и как исправить?

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь!!

Класс Contract

```
public class Contract {
    private Contract() {
    };

    public static final String AUTHORITY = "ru.test.slovartest.provider";
    public static final String URI = "content://" + AUTHORITY;

    public static final class Entry implements BaseColumns {
        public final static String TABLE_NAME = "rus";

        public static final Uri URI = Uri.parse(Contract.URI + "/" + TABLE_NAME);

        // Список заметок
        public static final String URI_TYPE_WORD_DIR = "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.ru.test.slovartest";

        // Одна заметка
        public static final String URI_TYPE_WORD_ITEM = "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.ru.test.slovartest";

        public final static String COLUMN_WORD = "word";
        public final static String COLUMN_TRANSLATION = "translation";
        public final static String COLUMN_FAVORITES = "favorites";

        public static final String[] LIST_PROJECTION = {
                _ID,
                COLUMN_WORD,
                COLUMN_TRANSLATION,
                COLUMN_FAVORITES
        };

        public static final String[] SINGLE_PROJECTION = {
                _ID,
                COLUMN_WORD,
                COLUMN_TRANSLATION,
                COLUMN_FAVORITES
        };
    }
}
```

Класс Provider

```
public class Provider extends ContentProvider {

    private static final UriMatcher URI_MATCHER = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    private static final int WORDS = 1;
    private static final int WORD = 2;

    static {
        URI_MATCHER.addURI(Contract.AUTHORITY, "words", WORDS);
        URI_MATCHER.addURI(Contract.AUTHORITY, "words/#", WORD);
    }

    private DBHeler dbHelper;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        dbHelper = new DBHeler(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projection, @Nullable String selection,
                        @Nullable String[] selectionArgs, @Nullable String sortOrder) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        switch (URI_MATCHER.match(uri)) {
            case WORDS:
                return db.query(Contract.Entry.TABLE_NAME,
                        projection,
                        selection,
                        selectionArgs,
                        null,
                        null,
                        sortOrder);

            case WORD:
                return db.query(Contract.Entry.TABLE_NAME,
                        projection,
                        selection,
                        selectionArgs,
                        null,
                        null,
                        sortOrder);

            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getType(@NonNull Uri uri) {
        switch (URI_MATCHER.match(uri)) {
            case WORDS:
                return Contract.Entry.URI_TYPE_WORD_DIR;

            case WORD:
                return Contract.Entry.URI_TYPE_WORD_ITEM;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Uri insert(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues contentValues) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        switch (URI_MATCHER.match(uri)) {
            case WORDS:
                long rowId = db.insert(Contract.Entry.TABLE_NAME,
                        null,
                        contentValues);

                if (rowId > 0) {
                    Uri noteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contract.Entry.URI, rowId);
                    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

                    return noteUri;
                }

                return null;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues contentValues,
                      @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Класс DBHelper

```
public class DBHeler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dictionary.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Context myContext;

    public DBHeler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
        try {
            DB_PATH = myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).toString();
            createDataBase();
            openDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {

            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // база не существует
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        String outFileName = DB_PATH;

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(database != null)
            database.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Класс CursorRecyclerAdapter

```
public abstract class CursorRecyclerAdapter<ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

    protected Cursor cursor; // Курсор
    protected boolean isDataValid; // Валидны ли данные
    protected int idColumnIndex; // Индекс столбца ID в курсоре

    public CursorRecyclerAdapter(Cursor cursor) {
        super();

        this.cursor = cursor;

        // Данные корректны если курсор не null
        isDataValid = cursor != null;

        // Пытаемся получить индекс столбца ID, если курсор не null, в ином случае -1
        idColumnIndex = cursor != null
                ? cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Contract.Entry._ID)
                : -1;

        // Каждый элемент имеет уникальный ID
        setHasStableIds(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        // Если данные некорректны — кидаем исключение
        if (!isDataValid) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cursor is not valid!");
        }

        // Попробовали перейти к определённой строке, но это не получилось
        if (!cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Can not move to position " + position);
        }

        // Вызываем новый метод
        onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, cursor);
    }

    public abstract void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor);

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (isDataValid && cursor != null) {
            return cursor.getCount();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        // Если с данными всё хорошо и есть курсор
        if (isDataValid && cursor != null) {

            // Если смогли найти нужную строку в курсоре
            if (cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {

                // Возвращаем значение столбца ID
                return cursor.getLong(idColumnIndex);
            }
        }

        // Во всех остальных случаях возвращаем дефолтное значение
        return RecyclerView.NO_ID;
    }

    /**
     * Заменяет старый курсор новым
     *
     * @param newCursor Новый курсор
     * @return Старый курсор или null
     */
    @Nullable
    public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
        // Если курсор не изменился — ничего не заменяем
        if (newCursor == this.cursor) {
            return null;
        }

        Cursor oldCursor = this.cursor;
        this.cursor = newCursor;

        if (newCursor != null) {
            idColumnIndex = newCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Contract.Entry._ID);
            isDataValid = true;

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            idColumnIndex = -1;
            isDataValid = false;

            // Сообщаем, что данных в адаптере больше нет
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, getItemCount());
        }

        return oldCursor;
    }


}
```

Класс WordsAdapter

```
public class WordsAdapter extends CursorRecyclerAdapter<WordsAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    public WordsAdapter(Cursor cursor) {
        super(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor) {
        int wordColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_WORD);
        String word = cursor.getString(wordColumnIndex);

        int translationColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_TRANSLATION);
        String translation = cursor.getString(translationColumnIndex);

        viewHolder.txtWord.setText(word);
        viewHolder.txtTranslation.setText(translation);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    /**
     * View holder
     */
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView txtWord;
        private final TextView txtTranslation;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            this.txtWord = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtWord);
            this.txtTranslation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTranslation);
        }
    }
}
```

Главный класс

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>  {

    WordsAdapter wordsAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvList);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this,
                layoutManager.getOrientation());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

        wordsAdapter = new WordsAdapter(null);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(wordsAdapter);


        getLoaderManager().initLoader(
                0, // Идентификатор загрузчика
                null, // Аргументы
                this // Callback для событий загрузчика
        );
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(
                this,  // Контекст
                Contract.Entry.URI, // URI
                Contract.Entry.LIST_PROJECTION, // Столбцы
                null, // Параметры выборки
                null, // Аргументы выборки
                null // Сортировка по умолчанию
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        wordsAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Никто не подскажет?

Comment: Может у вас просто данных в БД нет?

Comment: Есть более 10 тысяч записей

Comment: Вам надо локализовать проблему. Может у вас загрузка из БД не запускается. Или на запрос в БД данных БД не отдала. Или текст слился с фоном экрана. Или разметка вообще не та или в ней скрыты нужные элементы. Причин может быть тьма. Без отладки вам не ответить. А отлаживать - долго и нудно.

Comment: Я понимаю что причин тьма. Буду разбираться. Спасибо

Comment: Ольга, здравствуйте! Это Артем из Skillberg, напишите нам в ВК, мы вам поможем бесплатно.